# How to set Pointer values defined by Typedef Struct in a new function?

Tags: c, pointers, vector, struct, typedef

```
typedef struct Vector2D
{
  float x, y;
} Vector2D;

void Vector2DZero(Vector2D *pResult)
{
  pResult.x = 0;
  pResult.y = 0;
}
```

In function `Vector2DZero`, I want to set the values of `x` and `y` to 0 for a vector named `pResult`, though I'm not sure how to access the variables in a new function especially with a pointer. (I'm pretty sure what I've done is incorrect).

I HAVE to use the functions mentioned.

Do I need to use the arrow operator? Please help.

Comment: "Do i need to use the arrow operator?" - Yes. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Either arrow operator or (*pResult).x = ...

Comment: How about learning the basics from a reliable resource? YT videos or blogs are not a good way to learn C. Nor is trial&error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use dots

```
(*pResult).x = 0;
(*pResult).y = 0;
```

otherwide

```
pResult -> x = 0;
pResult -> y = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll try it and let you know :)

Comment: there is nothing to try. It is in any C book.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to use the arrow operator, as I did the code below with **x**, or you can use the dereference operator as I did with **y**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Vector2D {
    float x, y;
} Vector2D;

void Vector2DZero(Vector2D *pResult) {
    pResult->x = 0;
    (*pResult).y = 0;
}

int main(){
    Vector2D vec2d;
    Vector2DZero(&vec2d);
    printf("(%f,%f)\n", vec2d.x, vec2d.y);
    return 0;
}
```